# how to return a list to another list outside the function

Tags: python, list, function

I am making a game. in this game the user is asked a question.  if he gets it right it goes in the right_answer list and goes in the answer list. if he gets it wrong it goes into just the answer list.  plus they get a point for every correct question they get correct.  its going to be 8 questions and each one is a function.  this is question number one. The problem is it doesnt print anything.

```
def question_one(answer,right_answer,points):
answer = []
right_answer = []
print "how would you write this question in code so it would print"
answer=raw_input("< ")
#this is if he gets it right

if answer=="""print "how would you write this question in code so it would 
print""""":
#this is where the answers are inserted into the lists
    right_answer.append(answer)
# this is where the answer goes that they gave
    answer.append(answer)
    points=points+1
#this is if he gets it wrong
else:
    answer.append(answer)
#this is to return the values and the lists for the right answer and the 
answer
    return answer,right_answer,points    
(answer.append(answers),correct_answer.append(correct_answers), points)=question_one(answers,correct_answers,points)
```

Comment: You can't assign to an `append` call, or any other function or method call.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further? I'm confused as to what you're attempting on your last line of code

Comment: your answer string is invalid. You want `"""print "how would you write this question in code so it would print\""""` or `'''print "how would you write this question in code so it would print"'''` Python misinterprets 4 `"`s together, so you must escape the last one if you want to use double quotes.

Comment: what's the point of accepting any arguments if they're all virtually cleared within your function

Comment: the reason is because someone could get it wrong.  i wanted two lists one for right answers and one for the incorrect ones. so someone could find out what they got right and wrong.

Comment: you'd need to change the name of your variable you set to `raw_input()`. It's the same as the `answer` list, so you're really using `append` on a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% about what you're trying to implement, but here's an approximation of your code that works for me:

```
def question_one(answer, right_answer, points):
    '''
    The user is asked a question.
    If the answer is incorrect, it goes into the answer list.
    If the answer is correct, it goes into the right_answer list.
    '''
    answer_list = []
    right_answer = []
    print("What is 1 + 1?")
    answer = input()

    if answer == '2':
        right_answer.append(answer)
        answer_list.append(answer)
        points += 1
    else:
        answer_list.append(answer)

    return answer_list, right_answer, points
```

Comment: Keep in mind this person is using `python2`. `input` should be `raw_input` :-)